# Best way of doing popups / dialogs with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I previously did some popups / dialogs that I've now got regression error in () and want to recode to use JQuery for the DIVs / popups / dialogs. Moving to Jquery will be an advantage since we can enable repositioning and resize for dialogs / popups which we can't if the popup is just a DIV which places itself over the other elements.

Now I wonder what is the "best" way to make popups / dialogs / DIV appear with JQuery? I'd rather not add a plugin and only include the basic JQuery file. can you tell me how to do it?

The current page makes something like a popup but it is not repositionable.

Comment: What do you mean by best way exactly?

Comment: There should be a way to edit the CSS and reposition your current dialog box itself.

Comment: I would use a lightbox plug-in.

Comment: Why not use jQuery UI Dialog? You can show the content you want; but you'll have to also include the jQuery UI js. (and jQuery UI css). And you can change the styles for Dialog to be the same as your site interface.

Comment: By repositionable, you mean repositionable by the user? Or by the developer?

Comment: I don't know what to use and I mean repositionable by the user. The ansers below are not working and the links they link to are not examples of popups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do this is create a `.popup` class that contains the basic layout features for the popup. Then add this class to a hidden `<div>` at the top of the page.

Then when a popup is needed, attatch the `draggable` and `resizable` attributes of jQuery to it. After that, load the popup's content with a `.get()` request from a page dedicated for popup content and then `.show()` it.

**Example**

CSS

```
.popup 
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    // some other nice styling features
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class='popup'></div>
...
page content
...
</body>
```

Javascript

```
function popup(){
    // for the draggable you may want to specify the drag handle like only the title of the popup
    var popup = $('.popup');

    popup.draggable();
    popup.resizable();

    $.get('/getPopup.php?action=theKindOfPopupRequested', function(data) {        
        popup.html(data);
        popup.show('fast');
    });
}
```

Sources:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: -1 This did not work. The DIV is rendering and behind other element even though it is set to display:non and nothing happens when the script is activated.

Comment: You have to understand that this is not a plug-and-play piece of code. It is an example of the basic building block needed for the popup and needs customization. 
And regarding the div 'rendering' behind other elements, set `z-index: 9990;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rudimentary dialog plugin:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjUUQ/

```
(function($) {
    var dialogHTML = '<div class="dialog"></div>';

    $.openDialog = function(opts) {
        // Create the DIV for dialog without inserting into DO
        var dialog = $(dialogHTML);
        dialog.appendTo('body');

        // Give dialog some basic CSS
        dialog.css({
            position: 'absolute', // positioned
            'z-index': Math.pow(2,32) // make it sit on top
        });

        // Position the dialog on the screen
        var horizOffset = ($(window).width() - opts.width || dialog.outerWidht()) / 2;
        var vertOffset = ($(window).height() - opts.height || dialog.outerHeight()) / 2;
        dialog.css({
            left: horizOffset,
            right: horizOffset,
            top: vertOffset,
            bottom: vertOffset
        });

        // Return dialog object to make it chainable
        return dialog;            
    };        

}(jQuery));

$.openDialog({width: 200, height: 100}).append('hello world');
​
```

You can certainly add a lot to it, like handling key events to close on Esc, adding a titlebar with the buttons. But you probably already know how to do these things anyway.

Few things to note when creating dialogs:

- Set a high-enough z-index so that dialog is always on top
- Append the dialog element to `BODY`

In my experience, performance is somewhat better if the dialog HTML isn't always present on the page. This goes against graceful degradation, but the lighter the DOM tree, the faster the app seems to go. So it's best to add the dialog element to the tree as needed.

**EDIT:** Note that my dialog plugin does not expect you to have a predefined HTML on the page. It just conjures up a div. So, you don't select an element and *convert* it to a dialog. Instead, you create one anew.